# Heroku error Cannot find 'm3u8stream/lib/parse-time'

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I'm deploying my discord bot to Heroku, and everything seems to work fine when I run it locally. It seems to give this error all of a sudden, even though it worked fine before.

```
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896175+00:00 app[worker.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896215+00:00 app[worker.1]:     throw err;
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896218+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ^
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896220+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896222+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'm3u8stream/lib/parse-time'
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896225+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896227+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896229+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896231+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896233+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/info-extras.js:5:21)
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896235+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896237+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896239+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896241+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
2019-11-28T17:12:01.896243+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
2019-11-28T17:12:01.984705+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-11-28T17:12:01.968560+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "testbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.5.1",
    "discord.js-musicbot-addon": "^13.8.1",
    "googleapis": "^39.2.0",
    "htmlparser2": "^4.0.0",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "node-opus": "0.2.7",
    "node-static": "^0.7.11",
    "opusscript": "0.0.6",
    "parse-time": "^0.1.4",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "themememaker": "0.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a docker build. Please ensure that you can run your docker build locally.